# Overload operator<< for arrays

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, iostream

I want to overload `operator<<` for arbitrary arrays, such that the code `cout << my_arr` would work. First I tried to overload the second parameter of `operator<<` on `const T (&arr)[N]`, where `T` and `N` are template parameters. But testing the code revealed a side effect: `const char[]` also matches the type specification, and the new overload conflicts with the one defined in the stream class. Example code:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const T (&arr)[N])
{
    /* do stuff */
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "noooo\n"; /* Fails: ambiguous overload */
}
```

Can such an array printing operator still be implemented?

Comment: I don't think N will transfer well in a lot of cases.   `void f(int arr[], size_t N){ cout<<arr; }`

Comment: if you want an external library why not just use http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html

Comment: @Captain: `arr` actually has the type `int*` in that case, so it wouldn't match that overload.

Comment: @GeorgFritzsche You are correct. A simple test revealed "error: no matching function for call to ‘operator<<(std::ostream&, int*&)’" Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [overloading operator<< for arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9052624/overloading-operator-for-arrays)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<T, char>::value, std::ostream&>::type
operator<<(std::ostream& os, const T (&arr)[N])
{
    // ...
}
```

This will disable your overload when `T` is `char` using [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error).

For C++03, Boost has [`enable_if`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html) and [`is_same`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_same.html). Alternatively just roll your own:

```
template<class T, class U> struct is_same { 
    enum { value = false }; 
};
template<class T> struct is_same<T, T> { 
    enum { value = true }; 
};

template<bool, class T> struct enable_if {};
template<class T> struct enable_if<true, T> { 
    typedef T type; 
};
```

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: Use `boost::enable_if` and `boost::is_same` instead. If you don't want Boost, implement them yourself, these two are trivial.

Comment: @GeorgFritzsche: You're right.  But should it be?  I guess that `const T(&)[]` can bind to a non-const array also, so yeah, it's fine as written.  It's deeper levels of `const` that can't be added implicitly.